# How should I modify this compression code to prevent double-encoding?

Tags: c#, header, compression, response

I'm using the fairly standard compression code that I've seen floating around numerous places online:

```
HttpRequestBase request = context.HttpContext.Request;

string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding))
    return;

acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
{
    response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
    response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
}
else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
{
    response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
    response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
}
```

Under certain scenarios I have two separate pieces of code which try and compress the stream, but aren't aware that it has already been compressed. This results in my header looking like:

```
{Server=Microsoft-IIS%2f7.5&Content-encoding=gzip&Content-encoding=gzip&Location=%2fcsweb_IISVS2010%2fLogIn%3fReturnUrl%3d%252fcsweb_IISVS2010%252f&Set-Cookie=.ASPXFORMSAUTH%3d%3b+expires%3dTue%2c+12-Oct-1999+07%3a00%3a00+GMT%3b+path%3d%2f%3b+HttpOnly&X-AspNetMvc-Version=2.0}    System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase {System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection}
```

Where you can see Content-encoding=gzip has been written twice.

This scenario is handled fine by some browsers, but not all -- namely FireFox and Safari. As such, I need to check the header for this. I just want to make sure I am doing it properly.

It seems like the best way to do this is just to go:

```
if( response.Headers.Keys["Content-encoding"] ) { do stuff }
```

but [KeysCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.keyscollection.aspx) does not have a "HasKey" method. As such.. I could only see this approach working if I use exception handling as part of code-navigation -- I don't really want to do that.

My next thought was maybe I can clear the headers and then re-append, but looking at how much information is stored in the header already I think this would be a bad choice.

So.. this problem seems really easy to fix, but I'm not sure the right way to go about it. Any help?

EDIT: Just to be crystal clear...

In my web.config I have enabled "RadCompression" which is Telerik's implementation of compression for their controls. This is causing some responses to be compressed (but not all). Then, the above C# code is ran -- I need to detect that it has already been encoded.

EDIT2: Oh... easier than expected. The response.Headers actually contains two things -- "headers.Keys[index] as well as headers.AllKeys"

Doing something like response.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Content-Encoding") is sufficient.

Comment: Have you checked to verify that `response.Headers.Keys["Content-encoding"]` throws an exception if nothing is found. A lot of these collections actually just return null.

Comment: Haha, I haven't.. one sec. It just says in the documentation that it returns an ArgumentOutOfRangeException -- but who knows. One sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the ServerVariables collection would be a better place to keep track of whether this has been done on this request already?

```
context.HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["gzip-header-added"] = true;
```

#### Update

Headers.Keys is backed by a NameValueCollection, whose string indexer returns null if the item in question is not found: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb.aspx

So you should be good to check:

```
if( response.Headers.Keys["Content-encoding"] != null ) { do stuff }
```

Comment: While this solution is completely valid, and definitely better practice, it does not work for my scenario. The code above is where I am compressing it, but there is also a setting in web.config which will sometimes compress data. I don't have the ability to set that server variable for when it does it -- leaving me in the same position. I thank you for your insightful response, though!

Comment: Thanks for your help -- I've marked you as correct for the help.